# Accessing files outsude VMWare

Tags: oracle, vmware

I am running Oracle Enterprise Linux on VMWare. I now want to install Oracle which is is located on my C drive in Windows. Is there a way to copy this file to a folder in my virtual machine?

Comment: Definitively the wrong site for this kind of question...

Answer (score 1):

If its just once off, easiest way is to install winscp onto your windows host, setup a bridged or host only network on the vmware server and using winscp to copy the files in.

I think you can install vmware tools which would allow for shared folders, but last time I tried I ran into some issues and gave up.

Comment: +1 shared folders accross windows and linux is really a pain to set up

Comment: Cheers for the replies guys. Was looking and looking for a solution for ages. I ended up using Dropbox which worked perfect for my needs.